# Pass JSON in Javascript variable into a JQuery post

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am trying to get some data from a remote location by a JQuery post. It works great when I hardcode the data to post, but doesn't work when I put the JSON in a javascript variable, and then pass it in. As far as I understand, a JSON is just a string, so I'm not sure what the difference is.

so, this works:

```
$.post( PostURL, {var:"somevalue"}, function( data ) {
  // do something with data
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
jsonstring = '{var:"somevalue"}';

$.post( PostURL, jsonstring, function( data ) {
  // do something with data
}
```

obviously, I'm going to need to send different variables to get the stuff I need, so it can't be hard-coded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First example is an object, second is a string. You're not just putting it in a variable, you are changing its type.

Comment: @spenibus Thanks, didn't realize I had left quotes off the top one, changing the type and accidentally making it work. XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data in `post()` doesn't take JSON as an argument but an object, which is why the first code works. Your second code is using JSON, which is a string representation of an object rather than an actual object, therefore invalid.

> jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )
>
> **url**
>   Type: String
>   A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
>
> **data**
>   Type: PlainObject or String
>   A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Note that while it says that data can take a string, it is of the form `key=value&key=value`.

You don't need JSON, simply store the object in your variable rather than converting it to a string.

```
var myData = {var:"somevalue"};
$.post(PostURL, myData, function(data) {
    // do something with data
});
```

Comment: This answer helped me make the cleanest code (no juggling between string and JSON object), and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonstring =  JSON.parse('{var:"somevalue"}');

$.post( PostURL, jsonstring, function( data ) {
  // do something with data
}
```